# json template and python coding should not be tightly coupled to each other

Tags: python, json

I have a json file and after I load the file, python's json.loads converts it into dictionary. For example if i have a json file like,

```
{ "Family" : 
   { 
      "Father" : "Name of the person",
      "Mother" : "Name of the person",
      "Children" : [ 
          { 
              "Name" : "Name of the kid",
              "Age" : "Age value of the kid"
          } 
      ] 
}
```

I could access all the keys and values from the dictionary.

Question and requirement: I don't want to do a literal comparison like

```
if 'key' == 'Family':
    do some operations
elif 'key' == 'Mother':
    do other operations
else:
    do something else
```

The above json template if modified either the key or nesting, i want the keys and values to be updated immediately in my python code. I don't want the tight bonding between the python code and the json template. Is that possible???

I came up with 2 solutions, 
**1)** use constant values for keys. so any update to key in json template should also update the constant values in python code. But if nesting is changed then there is problem
**2)** use INI file to have mapping of json keys to some alias. so my INI file will be like

> [Family]
>   father : Father
>   mother : Mother
>   [etc...]

so the Python code will always refer to father, mother instead of the "json keys", in which way if json template is updated then INI file can be updated on the right hand side. Again this has the problem if json template is changed with the representation instead of just changing the key name.

Please let me know if there is any solution to this.

Comment: How often do you expect the JSON template to be modified?

Comment: based on requirement and use cases it could be modified quite frequently. In general i want to know if there is a tool or some means to achieve the requirement.

Comment: I'm also looking for a very good design of retrieving the values. In C, we have structs or macros. macros for keywords and structs to fill in the data from json. what is pythonic way of accessing the json(using the dictionary)???? I can use jsonschema to validate the data json. But implementation perspective of json/dictionary stumbles me. what is the right design??